# ob_start() Alternative for templates in PHP?

Tags: php, templates, output-buffering

**Question Updated**

I am building an MVC framework, for my templates and views, I will have a main page template file and my views will be included into this template.

The only way I have seen to do this is to use output buffereing

```
ob_start();
include 'userProfile.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Is there any other way of doing this?  I think output buffering is not the best on performance as it uses a lot of memory

Here is a sample controller, the `$this->view->load('userProfile', $profileData);`
 is the part that will be loaded using output biffering so that it can be included into the main template below into the $content part

**view class**

```
public function load($view,$data = null) {

    if($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        extract($data);
    } elseif($this->data != null) {
            extract($this->data);
    }

    ob_start();
    require(APP_PATH . "Views/$view.php");
    $content = ob_get_clean();
}
```

**controller**

```
/**
 * Example Controller
 */
class User_Controller extends Core_Controller {



    // domain.com/user/id-53463463
    function profile($userId)
    {
        // load a Model
        $this->loadModel('profile');  
        //GET data from a Model
        $profileData = $this->profile_model->getProfile($userId);

        // load view file
        $this->view->load('userProfile', $profileData);
    }
}
```

**main site template**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<?php echo $content; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using some that already exists such as Twig or Smarty?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion output buffering uses a lot of memory? Have you actually profiled the code and found out this is indeed the case?

Comment: If you want to put the rendered template in a variable, it will always consume at least the size of the rendered template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a template system is not necessarily tied to output buffering. There are a couple of things in the example code you give that should certainly not be taken for granted:

One:

```
flushblocks(); // what does this do??
```

And two:

```
$s = ob_get_clean();
```

Why does the code capture the template output into a variable? Is it necessary to do some processing on this before outputting it? If not, you could simply lose the output buffering calls and let the output be sent to the browser immediately.

Comment: Sorry flushblocks(); got left in there by accident, that shouldn't be in the example.  My main template file which would have the page layout (header, body, sidebar,  footer) is included into the page.  Thje body section has a variable $content which would be the content from the $s = ob_get_clean(); $s would hold the content from a particular view from my MVC